# Unable to download WebRTC from google chromium with git clone. Getting RPC failed

Tags: git, webrtc, chromium

This is exactly what happens when I try to clone the webRTC package from google using git.  What should I do?

```
Shyamals-iMac:~ shyamalchandra$ GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc Cloning into 'webrtc'...
* Couldn't find host chromium.googlesource.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
*   Trying 74.125.124.82...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to chromium.googlesource.com (74.125.124.82) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem   CApath: /usr/local/etc/openssl/certs
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=Mountain View; O=Google Inc; CN=*.googlecode.com
*  start date: Aug  8 13:12:55 2017 GMT
*  expire date: Oct 31 12:40:00 2017 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "chromium.googlesource.com" matched cert's "*.googlesource.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Google Inc; CN=Google Internet Authority G2
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /external/webrtc/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1 Host: chromium.googlesource.com User-Agent: git/2.13.1 Accept: */* Accept-Encoding: gzip Pragma: no-cache

< HTTP/1.1 200 OK < Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate < Content-Encoding: gzip < Content-Type: application/x-git-upload-pack-advertisement < Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1980 00:00:00 GMT < Pragma: no-cache < Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload < X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff < X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN < X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block < Date: Tue, 22 Aug 2017 12:47:39 GMT < Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="39,38,37,35" < Transfer-Encoding: chunked < 
* Connection #0 to host chromium.googlesource.com left intact
* Couldn't find host chromium.googlesource.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
* Found bundle for host chromium.googlesource.com: 0x7f9483c28930 [can pipeline]
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host chromium.googlesource.com
* Connected to chromium.googlesource.com (74.125.124.82) port 443 (#0)
> POST /external/webrtc/git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1 Host: chromium.googlesource.com User-Agent: git/2.13.1 Accept-Encoding: gzip Content-Type: application/x-git-upload-pack-request Accept: application/x-git-upload-pack-result Content-Length: 191

* upload completely sent off: 191 out of 191 bytes < HTTP/1.1 200 OK < Cache-Control: no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate < Content-Type: application/x-git-upload-pack-result < Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1980 00:00:00 GMT < Pragma: no-cache < Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload < X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff < X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN < X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block < Date: Tue, 22 Aug 2017 12:47:39 GMT < Transfer-Encoding: chunked < Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="39,38,37,35" <  remote: Sending approximately 148.48 MiB ... remote: Counting objects: 5630, done remote: Finding sources: 100% (69/69)
* OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 54
* Closing connection 0 error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 54 fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly fatal: early EOF fatal: index-pack failed
```

I already tried the following:

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
git config --global http.maxRequestBuffer 100M
git config --global core.compression 0
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try vi ~.netrc to open the .netrc file, which should be in your home dir and maybe empty.

Then add these:
`machine github.com
login technoweenie
password SECRET

machine api.github.com
login technoweenie
password SECRET

You can put your raw password but for security purposes, generate a password token here https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use instead and use it in place of your password.